# Importing OrbitControl.js gives uncaught type error

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm writing some Javascript that loads a glb 3d model into a webpage. Everything is working.

But as soon as I import the `OrbitControl.js` (either from my local folder or online) the browser gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*

Here's the full code:

```
import * as THREE from './three.js-master/three.js-master/build/three.module.js'
import {GLTFLoader} from './three.js-master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'
import { OrbitControls } from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"


const canvas = document.querySelector('.webgl')
const scene =  new THREE.Scene()

const loader = new GLTFLoader()
loader.load('assets/Prova.glb', function(glb){
    const root = glb.scene;
    root.scale.set(1,1,1)
    scene.add(root);
},function(xhr){
   console.log((xhr.loaded/xhr.total * 100) + "% loaded")
}, function(error){
    console.log('An error occured loading gltf')
})

const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1)
light.position.set(2,2,5)
scene.add(light)


const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width/sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.set(0,1,2)
scene.add(camera)




const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer

({
    canvas: canvas
})

renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true
renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding

controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

animate()
```

Comment: You should be importing all your components from the same build of Three.js, not from separate places like `https://threejs.org` & `three.js-master`. Also, if you're using a version from `r137` or above, make sure you use an `import-map`, which is outlined in [the installation section](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if u have notice the code in OrbitControls.js . Cuz it shows

```html
import {
    EventDispatcher,
    MOUSE,
    Quaternion,
    Spherical,
    TOUCH,
    Vector2,
    Vector3
} from 'three';
```

So which means this was import from 'three', and to solve this problem you may need change the 'three' into the address of your 'three.module.js'.
Because the original file of OrbitControls.js was for npm install.

Answer (score 1):

`OrbitControls` should be imported from the `examples` directory, just like you've imported `GLTFLoader`.

So you'll need something like:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
```

Or, since you're using `three.js-master` in the path:

```js
import { OrbitControls } from './three.js-master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
```

Comment: Importing from the examples directory gives me this error: GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/three.js-master/three.js-master/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Try adding `.js` behind `OrbitControls`

Comment: already tried adding  .js . It doesn't work